# External script (R) not working

Tags: sql, kognitio-wx2, wx2

When I try to run the external script (R Script) from kognitio console. I'm getting the below error message.

> Error:external script vfork child: No such file or directory

Can someone please help me to understand what it is!

Answer (score 0):

This will be because you have not replicated the script environment to all the DB nodes which are eligible to run the script.

Chapter 10 of the Kognitio Guide (downloadable from http://www.kognitio.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3), explains in section 10.2 how the script environment myst be identically installed in the same location on all nodes which will be used in processing, and section 10.6 explains how you can contrain this to a subset of nodes if for some reason you do not want the script environment to be on all nodes (e.g. if it has an expensive per-node licence).

You can use the wxsync tool to synchronise files across all nodes, or a remote deployment tool, such as HP's RDP, to ensure that the script environment is installed identically on all nodes.